# Skipped review audits with feedback

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

I'd like to suggest a new feature. Since I've unlocked the review feature, I've spent a lot of time doing that. Still, I often skip the questions on which I'm not sure enough or the question is ambiguous. I've probably even skipped lots of audits doing so, but SO doesn't give informations whenever you do that.

And here's my request: I'd really like that, if I skipped a review audit, SO gives me some advices on how I've should handled that. For example, if I skip a review for a question, a message like this could pop out:

> This was only a test to see if you were paying attention. You skipped it. If you were unsure about how you should have reviewed this question, flagging as "Too broad" or editing it were both correct actions. If you need more help, check our guidelines on questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

The benefit of doing that is the following: if I'm unsure about how to handle a specific category of questions it's likely that I will end up skipping at least an audit of that category. Then, looking at what other more experienced users did, I'd learn how to handle that by example.

Obviously, this is not intented as a replacement of the Help Center, but is thought as an integration. The review audit system is already a powerful instrument to prevent users from spamming random feedbacks just to obtain the badges. With this feature, it would also be kind of a method to get users **into the model of SO**.

Comment: `if I skip a review for a question, a message like this could pop out`: I think it would go against another trend SO tries to enforce, which is ["learn to love that skip button"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code/260246#260246).

Comment: @EricD. I don't think so... It's not like we are trying to "punish" who skips a question... The learn to love that skip button rule was introduced for user who don't take time to read in the Help Center. This is to help people how to categorize wrong question with examples. Because I kind of understand the meaning of "Too broad" as a flag, but the description itself doesn't say you can apply that to question which asks for code. And when you stumble on a question like that, if you have just started reviewing, you may be unsure on what to do... But this is only my opinion...

Comment: `The learn to love that skip button rule was introduced for user who don't take time to read in the Help Center` I don't think so. :) It's something every reviewer should consider. When not sure: *skip*. IMO, it applies to everybody.

Comment: Personnally, I wouldn't want a message to pop up when I skip an audit... because I skip *a lot* of suggestions. And so I would indeed feel, maybe not "punished", but certainly disappointed, if such a mechanism would slow me (or worse, stop me) reviewing. Audits are not perfect but I don't think they should be specifically brought to attention when we're not actually addressing one.

Comment: I'm with Eric -- I tend to skip a whole lot unless I'm 100% sure of my actions. I don't mind these auditing messages when I'm approving or rejecting, but for skipping, it seems like it would be annoying. Sometimes I skip ones just impatiently if I'm not in the mood even if I might understand the subject, since it's a bit too ambiguous/iffy. There are some days where I just want to see that really nice edit (or exceptionally bad one) to simplify my choices.

Comment: I like this idea, but that message would make me feel a bit like being punished. I suggest making it clear in the message that it's OK to skip, like replacing "You skipped it" with something like "You skipped it, which is OK, you are even encouraged to skip if you aren't sure", and possibly put that part in bold.

Comment: As a Reviewer with over 1000 reviews I would love such a function. It would bring clarity to Audits.  
Audit questions are usually the hardest ones to review and the ones in which some guidance will be most helpful.