# Can I view the votes on review questions I skipped?

Tags: discussion

As a new reviewer, I have a very high skip vs action ratio, since no-action is always better than getting it wrong.  While the feedback I get in the All Actions|Reviews tab in my profile is certainly useful, I thought it might be very informative to see how the vote actually went on the ones I skipped.

I'm not asking for a new feature like [Skipped review audits with feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310616/skipped-review-audits-with-feedback) - but just knowing how the vote actually went would help me to get better faster.

I looked on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/) but couldn't find anything. Perhaps there is a clever URL munging technique similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284293/6170930).

Or is this even possible at all?

Comment: If you want to know how other reviewers reviewed a task, without waiting for it to be completed, you can open it in incognito/private window in your browser (i.e. without being logged in).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history?skipped=true

There is a little checkbox at the bottom of each review queue's History tab:

[image: freehand RED circles ftw]

---

Or as Gothdo suggests in the comments:

Open the review task in a private/incognito window and you can monitor the votes as they come in. This is now my preferred method. It's fast, efficient and doesn't interrupt my workflow.